# Http Post with Partial URL in C#.NET

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have a web application (which I have no control over) I need to send HTTP post programatically to. Currently I've using HttpWebRequest like

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://someserver.com/blah/blah.aspx");
```

However the application was returning a "Unknown Server Error (not the IIS error, a custom application error page)" when posting to data. Using Fiddler to compare my Post vs IE post I can see the only difference is in the POST line of the request:

In Internet Explorer Fiddler (RAW view) shows traffic

POST /blah/blah.aspx HTTP/1.1

In my C# program fiddler (RAW view) records traffic as

POST https://someserver.com/blah/blah.aspx HTTP/1.1

This is only difference from both both requests.

From what I've researched so far it seems there is no way to make HttpWebRequest.Create post the relative URL.Note: I see many posts on "how to use relative URLs" but these suggestions do not work, as the actual post is still done using an absolute URL (when you sniff the HTTP traffic)

What is simplest way to accomplish this post with relative URL?

(Traffic is NOT going through a proxy)

Update: For the time being I'm using IE automation to do scheduled perf test, instead of method above. I might look at another scripting language as I did want to test without any browser.

Comment: Fiddler's RAW view ALWAYS shows the protocol and host in the request line, regardless of whether they were included there. Clients are expected to always send these in the Request Line if they know they're talking to a proxy (like Fiddler) and not inside an encrypted tunnel. There must be some other difference between the requests.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do POST without server in a Url.

One possible reason your program fails is if it does not use correct proxy and as result can't resolve server name.

Note: Fiddler shows path and host separately in the view you are talking about.

Configure you program to use Fiddler as proxy (127.0.0.1:8888) and compare requests that you are making with browser's ones. Don't forget to switch Fiddler to "show all proceses".

Here is article on configuring Fiddler for different type of environment including C# code: [Fiddler: Configuring clients](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp)

```
objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
objRequest.Proxy= new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The details I provided is from Fiddler RAW view. When loading page via IE the "POST" does not use full URL in the "raw" view. My code works for several other pages, on the same site, so proxy is not the issue. I also do several "POSTs" that succeed, there is just one page on the server (which I cannot control) that will only accept POST with relative URL (as IE submits it) While it seems WebRequest cannot do this, I'm looking for alternative methods. It seems if I use .NET I will have to create the HTTP requestw/o WebRequest (and is HTTPS)

Comment: so essentially i need someway to post to HTTPS with a relative URL. At the moment I can't figure it in .NET, i may look for alternate scripting languages, I just need to run a scheduled perf test on loading some pages/posting to form, and I need to be able to deploy it to run on XP&Win7 machines, preferably w/o any software install required.

Comment: No idea. More random things to try: request always contains server - check "Host: XXXXXX" header present in the view for requests from browser. Check if browser make HTTPS request, check if you can post/get other HTTPS pages from you code. With Fiddler - try to hack you program's request to work in "Composer" view - see what part makes request to fail.